# How to escape comma character in a javascript procedure in wherescape, snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, wherescape-red

I have a table with 2 columns:

| Tablename | Fieldname |
| --- | --- |
| tbl | name |
| tbl | LastName |

I need to display one row, having Fieldname values concatenated:
tbl --> name, lastName

So, I am using Listagg fct to concatenate the values :
listagg (fieldname,',') as newCol.

Running this command in Snowflake, works fine and displays want i need.
But, because we are using Wherescape to create procedures, adding this function in a javascript procedure, fails, because of COMMA separator used in listagg fct.
I tried with different escape characters, but nothing worked. (/,,/[])..
If I change the character in &,* it works, but I have to use comma.

Creating the newCol with listagg with & instead of ",", works and if I use a replace fct to change it to ",", it fails again :(

What should I use to have COMMA between the values for the newCol.
It is mandatory to have COMMA, because the column will be used in an update statement.

EDIT:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_myprocedure_test()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
language javascript
execute as CALLER
as
  $$
    
      const generateUpdStmt = ` SELECT 'UPDATE tbl SET ' || c.col_update  AS STMT_SQL
                                          ,c.col_update
                                    FROM  (
                                                select TABLE_NAME
                                                        , listagg (concat(field_name, ' = ''#tst''' ), ' , ') within group (order by TABLE_NAME, field_name asc)  as col_update 
                                                  from tbl
                                                  group by TABLE_NAME 
                                              ) c 
                                  ;`;

     

      try {

        var return_value = "Init: ";
        var stmt_update = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: generateUpdStmt});
        var result_stmt = stmt_update.execute();


     while  (result_stmt.next())
          { 
             
              var result_stmt_value_2 = result_stmt.getColumnValue(2);
                  return_value += result_stmt_value_2 +  "\n";
                                                            
                  
          } 
            result = "  Status: Succeeded. \n";


        }

  catch (err)  {
                result =  "Failed: Code:" + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
                result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
                result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
                return result; 
                }
          
  return return_value;

  $$
```

EDIT 2:
Returning result in wherescape with "&" instead of "," delimiter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WGxG.png)
Returning result in wherescape with "," delimiter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHwkS.png)

Comment: can you add the part of your JS responsible for creating the SQL?

Comment: done. i added a simplified version of the procedure

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine as JS and SQL. Could you please describe more on how it fails? It throws a SQL error, or it gives a wrong result when you run it in your env?

Comment: hi, it depends. running it in Snowflake, it works as expected. running it in wherescape, it fails because it returns only "lastname = '#tst'". somehow, it interprets the comma as a reserved character and it removes the  first part from the upd stmt. But this happens only in wherescape. Is there any setup made to wherescape?

Comment: Intresting. As per your screenshots in interprets only the first comma wrong. You have comma in two places, but it returns everything after the first comma, including the second comma. Is there any kind of default delimeter in wherescape? What would happen if you initialize your return_value as follows:  `var return_value = ",Init: ";` ?

Comment: wau... it acctually worked :)))  it displays correctly the update. It just removes the comma from Init .. magnifique! many thanks!

Comment: I am happy to know that it worked. It does not look right though. I believe we are missing something in wherescape that can explain the logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimal tbl table and when I run this:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE tbl SET ' || c.col_update  AS STMT_SQL
,c.col_update
FROM  (
select TABLE_NAME
        , listagg (concat(field_name, ' = ''#tst''' ), ' , ') within group (order by TABLE_NAME, field_name asc)  as col_update 
  from tbl
  group by TABLE_NAME 
) c ;
```

I get the following result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|                     STMT_SQL                     |            COL_UPDATE             |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| UPDATE tbl SET LastName = '#tst' , name = '#tst' | LastName = '#tst' , name = '#tst' |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I see your JS returns the same values. I edited it to return both columns as one string:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_myprocedure_test()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
language javascript
execute as CALLER
as
  $$
    
      const generateUpdStmt = ` SELECT 'UPDATE tbl SET ' || c.col_update  AS STMT_SQL
                                          ,c.col_update
                                    FROM  (
                                                select TABLE_NAME
                                                        , listagg (concat(field_name, ' = ''#tst''' ), ' , ') within group (order by TABLE_NAME, field_name asc)  as col_update 
                                                  from tbl
                                                  group by TABLE_NAME 
                                              ) c 
                                  ;`;

     

      try {

        var return_value = "";
        var stmt_update = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: generateUpdStmt});
        var result_stmt = stmt_update.execute();


     while  (result_stmt.next())
          { 
             
              return_value += result_stmt.getColumnValue(1) +  " | " + result_stmt.getColumnValue(2);
                                                            
                  
          } 

        }

  catch (err)  {
                result =  "Failed: Code:" + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
                result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
                result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
                return result; 
                }
          
  return return_value;

  $$  
  
call sp_myprocedure_test();

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 SP_MYPROCEDURE_TEST                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UPDATE tbl SET LastName = '#tst' , name = '#tst' | LastName = '#tst' , name = '#tst' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can you tell me what is expected?

Comment: Hi, i am expecting only the first part from return_result: UPDATE tbl SET LastName = '#tst' , name = '#tst'. Next step is to run this stmt and to perform the update in db. Ideea is that running it from snowflake, it works, it returns the stmt correctly. When calling the procedure from wherescape, it fails because of the comma delimitator and it returns only "name = '#tst'".. changing "," to "&" it returns "update tbl set lastName = '#tst' & name = '#tst'", which is not a sql syntax accepted, so it cannot be ran.  Have you tried to call the procedure in wherescape and you have the same result?

Comment: @Madelaine so the issue is not about JS or Snowflake, It's just about WhereScape. But if you will run this statement (as next step), why don't you also call it from SP?

Comment: yes, i will call it from SP, but this sp is created and run in wherescape. and the upd stmt will not run, because the upd stmt is not correctly generated (as i can see when trying to display the upd stmt generated).

Comment: Madelaine, the statement will be called inside the SP, so WhereScape's parsing feature shouldn't impact to its run.

Comment: hm.. not sure i get what should i do. I am running the stmt in while part, by adding this command: "/*var v_return_value = result_stmt.getColumnValue(1); var stmt_update_GDPR = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: v_return_value}); var result_stmt_GDPR = stmt_update_GDPR.execute();  result_stmt_GDPR.next(); return_value += "Result of SQL: " + result_stmt_GDPR.getColumnValue(1) +"\n"; */" and the execution fails because the upd is not generated well. I use while because i will have a list with more that 100 tables for which the upd should be created dynamically and run in the same time.